# Locus of line segments

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, locus

If we take a line segment of infinitesimally small length, and draw another line segment of the same length from the endpoint of the first at a particular angle and repeat this infinite number of times, what shape will we get? I think we might get a circle in one case and various spirals in the rest, depending on the angle, but I am not sure.

Comment: graph-theory is a tag about a different subject.

Comment: @Aryabhata, Whoops?

Comment: That is ok :-) just saying for future reference. (Also suggest reading the blurb of the tag...)

Comment: What is a "line segment of infinitesimally small length", and what is the angle between two of those?

Comment: @MartinR, I said infinitesimally small because I thought we can get smooth curves in angles $>90^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the angle is found in any regular polygon, i.e., is of the type

$$\frac{180^\circ(n-2)}n$$

then it will form an $n$-sided regular polygon, else it will form a spiral. This will intersect itself if the angle is less than $60^\circ$, and will form a circle as it approaches $180^\circ$.

Comment: Could anybody tell me the symbol for degrees?

Comment: Use this in LaTeX `$^{\circ}$`

Comment: @AvZ Thanks, I'll edit my answer.